# How to boost integer terms within Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to find a query for my data, that boosts all the numeric terms included.

For example:

```
A query on a field "description" contains these terms: 
"PatientA Disease II 12 A 7 Cell 348 go"
```

I am trying to get items from Elasticsearch whose "description" field contains similar terms to the above. Similar means especially similar with regard to the integer values contained in the search query. Additionally, all punctuation that is contained in the searched data should be ignored.

Desired results:

```
PatientA Cell Disease II 12 A 7 348 go
PatientB Disease II 12 A 7 Nucleus 348 go
PatientC, OK, II, 12 A, 7 Cell, 348 go
PatientD 7 Disease II 12-A Cell 348-go
```

The queries that I tried, always weigh every term the same and get distracted by punctuation. I found this post, that talks about boosting certain fields. [Elasticsearch "More Like This" API vs. more_like_this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300650/elasticsearch-more-like-this-api-vs-more-like-this-query)

However, how can I boost certain terms in a specific field?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that you can boost specific keywords by appending something like `some_keyword^10`.

while i find some references in my code, i have no clue where to look for documentation...

Comment: interesting feature. Need to try that.. could solve the problem

Comment: if you find some documentation, please leave a comment. i think it's some lucene syntax.