# Search text to find similarities

Tags: php, search, text, filter, elasticsearch

I'm building a website for a client that basically reunites lots of feeds from different sources.

My current problem is that the sources may have repeated content among them and I need to find a solution to compare the data received prior to publishing on the website.

My problem is that even though the content is repeated, some things might slightly change from source to source. *Example*:

**Source 1**:

> "Start your career in IT"

**Source 2**:

> "Start your career in Information Technology"

**Source 3**:

> "Starting your career in Information Technology"

So my question being: Is there a way to compare these texts and get a warning in case the content is similar (and by similar, as per the example, I mean similar which is not necessarily equal) to an existing content on the website?

Is it something elastic search could help me with?
I need directions, any, actually :)

Thanks

Comment: PHP has a function called **similar_text()**  you can find details on it here **http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php** .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer to the following link,
[Elasticsearch "More Like This" API vs. more_like_this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300650/elasticsearch-more-like-this-api-vs-more-like-this-query)
It answers a similar question